# Testing if either of two condtions are true

Tags: php

I'm trying to test if either of two variables are true using the code below, but I the code always returns the true conditions even when the variable is blank. Have I done this correctly or is it possible the variables are always true?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?php 
if (($gogo_team_member_twitter !== true) or ($gogo_team_member_facebook !== true)) {  
echo('class="amb-with-socal"');
}
else echo('class="amb-without-socal"');
?>
```

Comment: what are the values before the if statement if you echo them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need "Testing if either of two condtions are true" then your condition should look like:

```
if ($gogo_team_member_twitter === true || $gogo_team_member_facebook === true)
```

or just

```
if ($gogo_team_member_twitter || $gogo_team_member_facebook)
```

if you don't need strict comparison

Comment: In most cases the `=== true` is redundant and only serves to make the code less readable.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: yep, that's why I added a note after ;-)

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the different kinds of comparison? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles: sure, http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Scuzzy: why's that? `strpos` of what? PHP casts to boolean instantly, while strpos requires iterating over the string

Comment: @zerkms I didn't fill out the paramters to save comment space

Comment: @Scuzzy: and without the details your comment just makes no sense, just because `strpos()` is slower than type-casting

Comment: I think the point he's trying to make is that if you did `if(strpos('abc', 'a'))` to see if the string contained an 'a' you wouldn't get the results you were expecting.

Comment: @jprofitt: oh, get it. Sorry, I'm pretty slow this morning :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but you're checking that the variables are *not* true. Surely you want to check if either is true?

Also, try to use `||` and `&&` rather than `or` and `and`, as they have a higher precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I would just write

```
if ($gogo_team_member_twitter || $gogo_team_member_facebook)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition when dealing with negatives like this you can use "and"

```
if ($gogo_team_member_twitter !== true && $gogo_team_member_facebook !== true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are checking if any of the 2 variables is not exactly equal to true.

If the variable is blank, it is not true, and so the condition is met.